# User Activity log

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two database tables `users` and `activity_log` with dummy records as below:

Table  `users`

### id             name

1              Michael

2               Joseph

Table  `activity_log`

### id  user_id   activity

1   ---    1      ----------   you received $30 from Joseph

2    ---   1      ----------   you withdrew $20

My problem is that, I don't want to hard-code the name Joseph in the activity since the user might change his name in the future. I want when user 2 changes his name from Joseph, user 1 activity log will be updated accordingly with the new name.

As an example, I need activity log similar to that of Facebook where for example Michael can see in his activity log 'you liked Joseph's photo'. If Joseph changes his name to Jose, Michael will see in his activity log 'you liked Jose's photo'. How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use a package?

Comment: Hello @jeremykenedy, would you kindly suggest a package for that?

Comment: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger or https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog

Comment: i actually don't need activity loggger but activity log. As an example, I need activity log similar to that of Facebook where for example Michael can see in his activity log 'you liked Joseph's photo'. If Joseph changes his name to Jose, Michael will see in his activity log 'you liked Jose's photo'. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use the laravel-logger any way you like. You can make it log single events of your choice.

Comment: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-logger#trait-usage

Comment: okay, just a question, if Michael received $30 from Joseph, I want Michael to see in his activity log `you received $30 from Joseph` now later Joseph changes his name to Jose, how will I use the activity logger so that Michael views the activity with the new updated name like so `you received $30 from Jose`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save the `user_id` into the `activity_log` table and then reference it when rendering the message.

`activity_log` should contain id, owner_id, target_id, and activity_type.

Then you can create a function in the Activity model that'll render proper message accordingly to your requirements.

Comment: thanks @CodeTisans for the suggestion. would you kindly give me an example? I will appreciate

Comment: @MichaelMulai When an activity occurs you have to record it and populare `activity_log` table. For example when User with id 1 send money to user with id 2. You could fill the owner_id to 1, target_id to 2 and activity type to 'money_sent'. Then you could fetch those activities for either one of those users via relationships set in ActivityLog model. Then you can format a message like `{$activity->owner->name} sent you some money`. You can store additional data like the amount sent in additional field in the activity_log that could be cast to json.

Comment: I have being looking at spatie actvity_log package. can i utilize it to solve my issue?